# Java BorderLayout issues placing panels

Tags: java

I am new to Java GUI stuff and currently working on creating a microwave GUI. I am trying to place a panel within a panel but it's not really working as I think it should. I am using BorderLayout and basically putting a panel into BorderLayout.WEST and putting 2 panels within it (NORTH and CENTER). But somehow I can't add a panel to its CENTER, it seems like its going to NORTH all the time. Please see my code below.

```
private void buildFrame() 
{
        ovenLabel=new JLabel("Oven Area - Food goes here");
        add(ovenLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        ovenLabel.setBackground(Color.white);
        ovenLabel.setOpaque(true);
        ovenLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        ovenLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        ovenLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 5));

    //sidePanel
    side=new JPanel();
    add(side, BorderLayout.EAST);
    side.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 5)); //remove this later
    //top panel
    sideTop=new JPanel();
    sideTop.setBackground(Color.white);
    sideTop.setOpaque(true);
    sideTop.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    side.add(sideTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    displayLabel=new JLabel[3];
    for(int i=0;i<displayLabel.length; i++)
    {
        displayLabel[i]=new JLabel("");
        sideTop.add(displayLabel[i]);
    }
    displayLabel[0].setText("Cooking time is displayed here. . .");
    //bottom panel
    sideBot=new JPanel();
    sideBot.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 3));
    side.add(sideBot, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    buttons=new JButton[15];
    for(int i=0;i<buttons.length;i++)
    {
        buttons[i]=new JButton("test");
        sideBot.add(buttons[i]);
    }
    //button




}
```

Comment: Which component is it that's not ending up where you expect it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a `BorderLayout` , make sure that the container has `BorderLayout` as its layout manager, or the constraints (NORTH, etc..) will not be understood as they should :

```
side.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

(do this before adding anything to it)

If you call :

```
System.out.println(side.getLayout());
```

before doing the modification, you will see that your panel had a `FlowLayout` by default.

Comment: i forgot that the default layout is the FlowLayout.. i thought the default was BorderLayout!